# memory_profiler plot process id/name

Tags: memory-profiling

Is there a way to label the process id/name in the plot? Especially when enabling multi processes. Current legend displays child 0, 1 etc, but would be great if it can display process id/name.

[image]

mprof run -M python.exe app.py
mprof plot